# Is there any way to make my MacBook Pro react to a certain sound? Like a whistle?

Tags: audio

I was wondering if there's a Mac App or another kind of thing where when I make a certain sound the MacBook will react? I don't know if such a thing really exists, but if it does, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's **System Preferences : Speech : Speech Recognition** built in - not sure if it does what you want or not (it's more "voice command" than "sound/whistle" oriented - I haven't played with it enough to know if it will train to other sort of sounds easily - looks like not), but it's an easy place to start, if your "certain sounds" include "words".